# Setting up product options to generate part numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

I am trying to build a nice robust system in Rails to create products. At the top level I have Products, which are pretty generic (for example, T-Shirt). Each product can have unlimited Option Types (Size, Color), which in turn can have unlimited Option Values (Small, Medium, Large; Red, Blue, Green).

I set up my models so that Products have many Option Types, and Option Types have many Option Values.

Where I'm stuck is how to build Part Numbers. Part Numbers are individual values that are created based on the selected Option Types/Values for a given Product. For example, TSHIRT-LG might be the part number for a T-Shirt with Size: Large, and Color: Green selected.

I guess my strategy so far has been to associate Part Numbers with Products and Option Values. In the back end, an administrator should create Part Numbers by selecting combinations of Option Values belonging to Option Types belonging to a Product. On the front end, a user should be able to select their preferred options, and then see the correct Part Number appear based on their selections. I've created a Product form using nested models, based on http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised. Creating Options hasn't been a problem, but I'm stuck on how to build the form to create Part Numbers based on Option Values. I'd like to do drop-down menus to choose existing Option Values, but I just can't get my head around making it work.

Comment: You discuss creating part numbers, but who creates parts?  Is each part created by a person, or does the system itself create new parts by combining option values in different ways?

Comment: Thanks for the response Walter. A problem is that the current part numbers are unfortunately a bit sporadic with their syntax from product to product, and as such cannot be automatically created by the system based on option values. A person needs to physically assign part number names to option combinations.

Comment: What is a part?  (This is the kind of stupid sounding question that has to be asked all the time during data analysis)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to decide how exactly you want to code your part-numbers and what attributes you want to take to create the part numbers and what you want them to look like.

e.g TSHIRT-XLG-M-P-001

Have a fields called part_no, and as the admin creates items

```
before_save: create_part_no
validates_uniqueness_of :part_no

def create_part_no
  name + '-' + size + '-' + gender+ '-' + id
end
```

if you want it changeable by the admin remove the before_save and

```
<%= f.text_field :part_no, default => :create_part_no %>
```

some ajax may be required

Comment: Thank you for the response. To answer Walter above, and which also applies to your solution, the part numbers need to be entered by a person, because unfortunately the existing part numbers were arbitrarily created and don't follow any ordered pattern of name, size, gender, etc.

Comment: I'm going to attempt the part number creation in a separate form. I'll post the results to see if maybe there is a better way than how I'm doing it. Thank you again.

Comment: having standardised part numbers will save you a lot of future grief, you can always have two part no fields. `part_no` and `part_no_old` for legacy. Create the initial drop-downs in the 'new', that create the partno as above see [here](https://github.com/maxcobmara/scamper/blob/master/app/models/asset.rb) under suggested_serial_no for ideas

Answer (score 1):

Ryan also has an older but great screen cast on dynamic select menus: http://railscasts.com/episodes/88-dynamic-select-menus

Maybe it helps!

Comment: Thank you, this will be helpful.